# Geometric Interpretation of a spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3},\vec{v_4}$ be non-zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that the solution of $[\vec{v_1} \vec{v_2} \vec{v_3} \vec{v_4}|0]$  is a hyperplane. What is the geometric interpretation of Span$\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3},\vec{v_4}\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $A$ the matrix of $v_i$ vectors.
Then the solution set of $x:\, Ax=0$ is called the *kernel* or *nullspace* of $A$, and the span of its column vectors $v_i$ is called the *image* (or *range*) or *column space* of $A$. Its dimension is the *rank* of $A$

By the *rank-nullity theorem*, as a hyperplane in 4 dimensions has dimension $3$, we get the rank to be $\dim{\rm span}(v_1,v_2, v_3, v_4)=4-3=1$.
So this span is a **line** through $0$.